# Split a file to multiple files automaticaly in VIM?

Tags: vim

I'm new in VIM and I try to split a file in multiple files.This is a test file:

```
Something1;XXXword;blabla(about 500 signs);
Something1;XXXword;(about 500 signs);
Something1;YYYword;(about 500 signs);
Something1;RRRword;(about 500 signs);
```

XXX could be a word 2-20 characters long. When the following word (XXX/YYY/RRR) changes then before "Something1" should be a cut and the following lines till XXX changes should be an another new file and so on.

It should be so:

```
File1:
Something1;XXXword;blabla(about 500 signs);Something1;XXXword;(about 500 signs);

File2:
Something1;YYYword;(about 500 signs);

File3:
Something1;RRRword;(about 500 signs)
```

Is there a way to do this like a pro? Thanks :)

Comment: Does it have to be vim? Sometimes things are simpler jumping out to the shell and do some e.g. python...

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend a different tool, like Awk.

```
awk -F';' '{printf "%s", $0 >> $2}' your_file.txt
```

This will split each line into columns separated by `;`. Each line will be appended (`>>`) to a file named after the 2nd column, `$2` (e.g. XXXword). Append/print the whole line, `$0`, except the newline (`printf "%s"`) to the new file so everything is one long line.

Note: I am using `gawk` as my `awk` implementation, you may need to make adjustments depending on your `awk` implementation.

#### For the more complex scenario

In the following case where you had `XXX`, `YYY`, `XXX`:

```
Something1;XXXword;blabla(about 500 signs);
Something1;YYYword;(about 500 signs);
Something1;XXXword;(about 500 signs);
```

If this should yield 3 files (1 `YYY` file and 2 `XXX` files) then we can use Awk as well:

```
awk -F';' 'last != $2 {f[$2]++} {printf "%s", $0 >> $2 f[$2]; last = $2}' your_file.txt
```

This will yield files: `XXXword1`, `XXXword2`, and `YYYword1`

This is the similar to the awk example above except we use a dictionary/array to store the number of times the 2nd column changes, `f[$2]++`, from the previous line `last != $2 {...}`. Making sure to set `last` to the 2nd column after printing each line. Output the line, `$0`, to a file named after `$2 f[$2]` (adjacent variable and string will be concatenated).

Comment: You beat me to it.. This is definitely a job for `awk`!

Comment: What would it look like if we want `XXX\nYYY\nXXX` in 3 different files as the question seems to imply?

Comment: @LucHermitte, I'm sorry I am confused by your question. This does yield 3 different files based on this test data, e.g. `XXXword`, `YYYword`, and `RRRword`. It redirects the whole line, `$0`, to a file named after the 2nd column, `$2` in `printf "%s", $0 >> $2`

Comment: The question used indeed  the sequence `XXX`, `YYY` and `RRR` and isn't entirely explicit about cases such as `XXX`, `YYY`, `XXX`. In the question, @Darius Schindler said `"When the following word [...] changes [...] should be an another new file"` If this new sequence shall end up in only two files, then there is a (convoluted) one-liner purely in vim script.

Comment: For the `XXX`, `YYY`, `XXX` scenario where you will end up with 3 files, I would do something like this: `awk -F';' 'last != $2 {f[$2]++} {printf "%s", $0 >> $2 f[$2]; last = $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to program it as you would have programmed it in any other language. My first reflex would have been Perl BTW.

```
function! s:split(root) abort
  " todo: check empty buffers
  let lines = getline(1, '$')
  let nb_lines = len(lines)
  let files = []

  let crt = 0
  while crt < nb_lines
    " I suppose the word is the second field in a .csv file
    let word = matchstr(lines[crt], '^[^;]*;\zs[^;]*\ze;')
    " This is where the real magic happens, see :h /\@!
    let next = match(lines, '^[^;]*;\(\('.word.'\)\@![^;]\)*;', crt)
    if next == -1 | let next = nb_lines | endif
    let files += [ lines[crt : (next-1)] ]
    let crt = next
  endwhile

  echo files
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 SplitBuffer :call s:split("<args>")
```

Instead of `let files += [ something ]`, you will want to execute

```
:let index = 0
...
:for...
    ...
    :call writefile(a:root.index, lines[crt : (next-1)])
    :let index += 1
:endfor
```

EDIT:

In case the sequence `XXX`, `YYY`, `XXX` shall lead to two files instead of 3, it can be done with this (convoluted and untested) oneliner -- still, prefer @Peter Rincker's awk based solution.

```
:call map(getline(1, '$'), 'writefile(v:val, split(v:val, ";")[1], "a")')
```